# How to obtain a list of all Rundeck jobs dispatched to a node?

Tags: rundeck

Given a node hostname, I would like to obtain a list of all jobs that are dispatched to that particular node.

The list can be obtained either via the Rundeck web interface, or by a SQL query run directly in the Rundeck database.

How would one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. The Rundeck web interface is pretty basic, so we'll have to resort doing a SQL query.

To find all jobs dispatched to node *foobar*, connect to the Rundeck MySQL database and run:

```
mysql> SELECT id, group_path, job_name, date_created, filter, uuid FROM scheduled_execution WHERE filter LIKE '%foobar%'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
          id: 42
  group_path: ABC/XYZ
    job_name: My Job Name
date_created: 2016-06-10 13:38:37
      filter: name: foobar.*
        uuid: 75eaaee1-0d04-43bc-a7ec-2587bc8f61ac
*************************** 2. row ***************************
          id: 47
  group_path: ABC/XYZ
    job_name: Another Job Name
date_created: 2016-06-10 13:38:37
      filter: name: foobar.*
        uuid: bea25d9d-cd50-4016-b195-0ba9e98c8782
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```